# Como funciona a criação de um Array?

Tags: java, array, construtor, instanciar-objeto

Ao usar o comando `new()` para a criação de qualquer objeto chamamos o construtor da classe desse objeto e obtemos a referência para a instância criada. Entretanto, o que ocorre na criação de um Array?

Para onde aponta (sei que esse termo é incoerente em relação a Java, pois não estamos trabalhando com ponteiros) a referência retornada na criação? Entendo que não é para um objeto do tipo, pois não estamos usando o construtor da classe.

Comment: Aponta para o mesmo lugar quando você faz int a = 6; String a = "";

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Arrays são objetos

A [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) sobre Arrays diz que eles são objetos que contém um número fixo de valores de um determinado tipo.

Isso pode ser provado pelo seguinte código:

```
String[] array = new String[10];
System.out.println(array instanceof Object);
```

O resultado é:

> true

## Arrays têm múltiplas personalidades

Há um motivo para a sintaxe especial na criação de arrays. Cada array instanciado com um tipo diferente gera uma nova classe dincamicamente.

Suponha a criação de dois arrays abaixo:

```
String[] array1 = new String[10];
Integer[] array2 = new Integer[10];
```

Se você imprimir o nome das classes desses objetos assim:

```
System.out.println(array1.getClass().getName());
System.out.println(array2.getClass().getName());
```

Vai ver que eles retornam valores diferentes, como a seguir:

> [Ljava.lang.String;
>   [Ljava.lang.Integer;

Podemos verificar que os tipos são incompatíveis entre si:

```
System.out.println(array1.getClass().isAssignableFrom(array2.getClass()));
```

Do que obtemos:

> false

## Listas são diferentes

Como um contra-exemplo, listas que usam genéticos **não** apresentam o mesmo comportamento.

Considere as listas:

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
```

Se imprimirmos as classes, veremos que o *type erasure* foi efetivo, pois são idênticas:

> java.util.ArrayList
>   java.util.ArrayList

E podemos verificar que elas são compatíveis entre si usando:

```
System.out.println(list1.getClass().isAssignableFrom(list2.getClass()));
```

Do qual obtemos:

> true

## Construtor

Arrays não possuem construtores no sentido tradicional, isto é, você não pode estender a classe e sobrescrever o construtor.

Entretanto, como todo objeto ele terá seu estado inicializado em algum ponto pela Máquina Virtual.

Isso pode ser uma desvantagem do ponto de vista de flexibilidade da linguagem, assim como ocorre com tipos primitivos. Por outro lado, isso permite que a JVM otimize a alocação do array sem depender de código Java.

## Armazenamento

Arrays alocam um trecho contínuo de memória, cujas posições são acessadas através do índice. Cada posição contém um *elemento*.

Os elementos contém diretamente os valores no caso de tipos primitivos, enquanto objetos são armazenados como referências. Isso faz com que em um novo array de primitivos os elementos sejam inicializados com o valor padrão daquele tipo, enquanto arrays de objetos tem seus elementos inicializados com `null`.

## Referências vs. Ponteiros

Já existe conteúdo aqui no SO sobre isso, mas basicamente uma referência é algo que sempre aponta para um objeto e que permite o acesso ao mesmo somente através da interface ou tipo da referência usada.

Você não pode apontar uma referência para uma posição arbitrária em memória ou executar operações matemáticas sobre elas.

Answer (score 3):

Está usando o construtor sim. É algo interno, a sintaxe é um pouco, mas no fundo está usando um construtor.

```
int[] a = new int[10];
```

Se não houvesse uma sintaxe própria na linguagem, seria escrito assim:

```
Array<int> a = new Array<int>(10);
```

Ou

```
int[] a = {1, 2 , 3};
```

Seria:

```
int[] a = new Array<int>(3);
a[0] = 1;
a[1] = 2;
a[2] = 3;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Collections/Array.java).

Não sei se entendi sobre o ponteiro, mas não há diferença do resto. Pelo contrário, muitas vezes os objetos acabam usando um *array* interno para sua constituição.

A criação do *array* é igual a qualquer objeto, é alocado memória no [*heap*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101) e eventualmente dados são armazenados ali, caso contrário é inicializado com um valor padrão (zero de acordo com o tipo). O endereço alocado será a referência guardada na variável.